# How to send e-mail in oracle 11g without password authentication?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I created a `pl/sql package` that will send `e-mail` with the username and password authentication. Is it possible to send an e-mail in oracle 11g without requesting password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a question for your mail server administrator.  It is entirely possible to send email without requesting authentication if your mail server doesn't require authentication.  If your mail server requires authentication, however, whatever language you use to send email will need to provide the authentication.